# Why is one of my print functions deleting nodes?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

OK so I have a print function for my binary tree program that prints everything in Breadth-First. When I call it, it prints in the order that I would expect it to, however it also deletes all but ones of the nodes and leaves me with an empty tree.

```
void BST::breadth(Node *& cur_root)
{
    if (cur_root != NULL) {
        cout << cur_root->m_value;
        if (cur_root->m_left != NULL) { 
            myqueue.push(cur_root->m_left);
        }
        if (cur_root->m_right != NULL) {
            myqueue.push(cur_root->m_right);
        }
        if (!myqueue.empty()) {
            cout << ", "; 
            cur_root = myqueue.front();
            myqueue.pop();
            breadth(cur_root);
        } else {
            cout << "}" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I assumed that popping the node off of myqueue might have been the problem, yet I don't have this problem when I use my normal print function (In-Order Traversal).

```
void BST::print(Node *& cur_root)
{
    if (cur_root != NULL) {
        print(cur_root->m_left);
        myqueue.push(cur_root);
        print(cur_root->m_right);
    }
    int sizecompare = myqueue.size();
    if (size() == sizecompare) {
        while (!myqueue.empty()) {
            cout << myqueue.front()->m_value;
            myqueue.pop();
            if (!myqueue.empty()) {
                cout << ", ";
            }
        }
        cout << "}" << endl;
    }
}
```

They both use the same queue of nodes, so I don't understand why they would behave differently when popped. So is the pop function the culprit? If so, why does it only happen on one function? Is there a way I can work around it so my nodes aren't destroyed?

Comment: because of `myqueue.pop();`

Comment: Or because you re-assign `cur_root = myqueue.front();`?

Comment: what is `size()` return in your 2nd code block?

Comment: Why you are passing pointer by reference if the idea is just to print values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are passing `cur_root` by reference instead of by value.  When your `breadth` function returns, your `cur_root` is pointing to something else (the end of the tree).

You can also avoid the recursion:

```
void BST::breadth(Node* root)
{
    std::queue<Node*> myqueue;
    myqueue.push_back(root);
    bool first = true;

    cout << "{";

    while (myqueue.empty() == false) {
        cout << (first ? "" : ",");
        first = false;

        Node* current = myqueue.front();
        myqueue.pop();

        cout << current->m_value;

        if (current->left) {
            myqueue.push(current->left);
        }
        if (current->right) {
            myqueue.push(current->right);
        }
    }

    cout << "}" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Oh my God, I was tearing my hair out for hours before I asked it and just as I posted it I realized that might be the problem. You were right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
void BST::breadth(Node *& cur_root)
```

Takes in a reference to a pointer.

```
cur_root = myqueue.front();
```

Changes it to be one of the child nodes. You just overwrote it.